# function call to set innerHTML is not working - gives Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the innerHTML for a div element dynamically through a called Javascript function. While the function is being called and printing the debug messages correctly, the innerHTML is "Undefined". I can't figure out why -any help will be much appreciated.

Here's what I wrote:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var clientsHealthStat = function (color) { // color is the RED / YELLOW / GREEN status of the client
    var ClientPerfsREST = 'http:/localhost:8081/c3rests/c3/ClientPerfs';
    var ClientCntr = 0; // provide the count of clients for the specific status
    $.getJSON(ClientPerfsREST, function(ClientPerfsJson){
      $.each(ClientPerfsJson.payload.array,function(i,performance){
        if (performance.attributes.Status === color) { ClientCntr++; }
      }); // End of loop through result set
      return ClientCntr; // return the client count with Health Color
    }); // End of getJSON(SummaryPerfsREST, function())
  }
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var parentElement = document.getElementById('customerHealthSummary');
    var healthStatusIndicators = ['red','yellow','green'];
    for (var i = 0; i < healthStatusIndicators.length; i++) {
      var childElement = document.createElement('div');
      childElement.style.width = '100%';
      childElement.style.backgroundColor = healthStatusIndicators[i];
      childElement.title = healthStatusIndicators[i].toUpperCase();
      console.log(clientsHealthStat(healthStatusIndicators[i].toUpperCase()));
      childElement.innerHTML = clientsHealthStat(healthStatusIndicators[i].toUpperCase());
      parentElement.appendChild(childElement);
    };
  }); // End of document ready function
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clientsHealthStat` is an async function (well, the `getJSON` call is async) - you need to use a callback:

```
var clientsHealthStat = function (color, callback) { // color is the RED / YELLOW / GREEN status of the client
    var ClientPerfsREST = 'http:/localhost:8081/c3rests/c3/ClientPerfs';
    var ClientCntr = 0; // provide the count of clients for the specific status
    $.getJSON(ClientPerfsREST, function(ClientPerfsJson){
        $.each(ClientPerfsJson.payload.array,function(i,performance){
            if (performance.attributes.Status === color) { ClientCntr++; }
        }); // End of loop through result set
        callback(ClientCntr);
    }); // End of getJSON(SummaryPerfsREST, function())
}
```

And then call the function:

```
clientsHealthStat(healthStatusIndicators[i].toUpperCase(), function(data) {
    childElement.innerHTML = data;
});
```

In your code, you called the function and tried to return before the `getJSON` call ever finished, hence why you were receiving an `undefined` error. Callbacks allow for the function to run and when it's finished, it'll run the function you pass in.

Comment: Also, since you're already using jQuery to handle your document ready event, why not use it to do your DOM manipulation as well? Check out the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method for instance...

Comment: @tymeJV, Thank you for clearly explaining what I was doing wrong. Before I accept the answer in its entirety, a small follow up question. When I make the changes you suggested, I am seeing the following output: `<div title="RED" style="width: 100%; background-color: red;"></div><div title="YELLOW" style="width: 100%; background-color: yellow;"></div><div title="GREEN" style="width: 100%; background-color: green;">6</div></div>` In other words the 'data' is not being set for the first two loops, though the childElement is getting created properly. Can you please explain the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Okay further explorations along the same line @tymeJV suggested led me to figure out the issue. Changing callback(ClientCntr) to callback(ClientCntr, color), and then using the color in place of healthStatusIndicators[i] to set the values in the for loop forced the timing due to the async calls. Thanks to all for the correct pointers.